# The space $C^1([0,T]\times \Omega)$ for $\Omega$ open and bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be open and bounded.

Is there anything nice I can say about the space $C^1([0,T]\times \Omega)$ and its inclusion in some Bochner like spaces?

If $f \in C^1([0,T]\times \Omega)$ then it is not true that $f \in C^0([0,T]; C^1(\Omega))$. And I don't think it's even true that $f \in C^1([0,T]; C^0(\Omega)).$ How about if we say $f$ (and some of its derivatives) are bounded for all $x,t$?

My reason for asking this is I want to know: If $f \in C^1([0,T]\times \Omega)$ and $g \in C^1_c((0,T); W^{s,p}(\Omega))$ then does the product rule apply: $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$ (the $'$ means the time derivative)

Comment: How do you define the Bochner space when the codomain of the functions is not a Banach space? Do you use semi norms or something?

Comment: @user43687 Hmm. So $C^0([0,T];X)$ is defined as functions $f$ that are continuous in the sense that $|f(t_n)-f(t)|_X \to 0$ if $t_n \to t$, and $sup_{t\in [0,T]}|f(t)|_{X}$ is finite.  When $X$ is not Banach.. I don't know if it makes sense.

Comment: I don't strictly need the results in the third paragraph, if they were true they would help me to answer the fourth paragraph.